# CSS Reset interferes with main CSS stylesheet and clearfix does not work

Tags: html, css, clearfix

```css
/* Don't erase box-sizing */

*{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Don't erase .group */

.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

body {
    background: #cccccc;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #666666;
    margin: 0;
}

a{
    color: #f58220; 
}

#main_wrapper{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
    background: #333333;
    padding: 30px 0 0 0;
}

.logo a{
    display: block;
    width: 133px;
    height: 46px;
    background: url(http://www.teamusa.org/~/media/USA_Fencing/Logo/Nike-Fencing.png?la=en);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    margin: 0 0 25px 20px; 
}

.primary ul {
    background: #666666;
}

.primary ul li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #333333;
}

.primary ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.content_wrap {
    background: e5e5e5; 
}

#main_content {
    background: #ffffff;
    float: left;
    width: 660px;
}

aside {
    width: 300px; 
    background: #e5e5e5;
    float: right;
}

footer {
    clear: both;
    background: #333333;
    height: 50px;
}

/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML}>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Yonsei Fencing</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index5.css" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    
<body>
<div id="main_wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1 class="logo"><a href="#" title="cool image">This is an image</a></h1>
        
        <nav class="primary">
        <ul class="group">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
        
    </header><!--end header-->
      
<div class="content_wrap" group>  
    <section id="main_content"> 
       <article class="posts"><img class="thumbnail" src="#" alt="thumbnail">
       <div>
           <h1><a href="#" title="">This is a Lorem Ipsum Heading</a></h1>
           <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
           <a href="#" title="readmore">Read More</a>
       </div>
       </article>
       
         <article class="posts"><img class="thumbnail" src="#" alt="thumbnail">
       <div>
           <h1><a href="#" title="">This is a Lorem Ipsum Heading</a></h1>
           <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
           <a href="#" title="readmore">Read More</a>
       </div>
       </article>
       
         <article class="posts"><img class="thumbnail" src="#" alt="thumbnail">
       <div>
           <h1><a href="#" title="">This is a Lorem Ipsum Heading</a></h1>
           <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
           <a href="#" title="readmore">Read More</a>
       </div>
       </article>
       
         <article class="posts"><img class="thumbnail" src="#" alt="thumbnail">
       <div>
           <h1><a href="#" title="">This is a Lorem Ipsum Heading</a></h1>
           <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
           <a href="#" title="readmore">Read More</a>
       </div>
       </article>
       
         <article class="posts"><img class="thumbnail" src="#" alt="thumbnail">
       <div>
           <h1><a href="#" title="">This is a Lorem Ipsum Heading</a></h1>
           <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
           <a href="#" title="readmore">Read More</a>
       </div>
       </article>
    </section><!--end main_content-->
            
    <aside>
        <div class="side_box">
            <h2 class="sidebar_heading">Sidebar Links</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Link 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--end sidebox-->
        
        <div class="side_box">
            <h2 class="sidebar_heading">Text Widget</h2>
            <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </br></br>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
        </div><!--end sidebox-->
    </aside><!--end sidebar-->
</div><!--end content wrap-->   
            
    <footer>
        <small>Copyright <a href="#">WebSite.</a> All rights reserved.</small>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hello, beginner coder here.

My CSS Reset (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) that's on a separate stylesheet (I combined both CSS stylesheets here) seems to interfere with my main stylesheet by disabling the black background color on my header around my logo. The font-size and line-height in the body will not change either. Also, the ".group:after" (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) is supposed to fill in the missing background color gap in my sidebar, but an empty space remains...

Help?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semicolon after the `background` property in your `header` selector.

Comment: Thanks for helping me get that part fixed! Still not sure what to do for the rest..